# Grails MongoDB - how to print the _id on a gsp page

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, gsp

I want to print the _id (${oid} present in my mongo object. I can see it in the object when i print the whole object , but when i try to reference it in my gsp page it can not access to it.
I don't understand why?

this my method of the controller

```
    def index_mod(Integer max) {
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
        DB chloroKB = mongoClient.getDB("ChloroKB");
    log.debug("DB : " + chloroKB)

    def crossref = chloroKB.getCollection("CrossReference_URL")
    log.debug("crossref : " + crossref)

    def crossrefList = new ArrayList<CrossReference_URL>()
    def crossrefCount = 0
    DBCursor cursor = crossref.find()
    try {
        while(cursor.hasNext()) {
        def nextCrossRef = cursor.next()
        log.debug(crossrefCount + " - " + nextCrossRef)
        crossrefList.add(nextCrossRef)
        crossrefCount++
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }

    log.debug("list CrossRef : " + crossrefList)

        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    model:[count: crossrefCount, crossReferenceList: crossrefList]//CrossReference_URL.list(params)]
   }
```

and this is the table where i want to print it in my gsp page :

```
<table>
      <!-- SBO - test what is in the crossReference_URLInstanceList -->
      <tr><th>crossReference_URLInstanceList : ${crossReferenceList}</th></tr>

      <thead>
    <tr>
      <g:sortableColumn property="crossref_source" title="${message(code: 'crossReference_URL.id.label', default: 'Id')}" />

      <g:sortableColumn property="crossref_source" title="${message(code: 'crossReference_URL.crossref_source.label', default: 'Crossrefsource')}" />

      <g:sortableColumn property="crossref_url" title="${message(code: 'crossReference_URL.crossref_url.label', default: 'Crossrefurl')}" />

      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <g:each in="${crossReferenceList}" status="i" var="list">
    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
      <td>${list.id}</td>

      <td><g:link action="show" id="${list._id}">${list.crossref_source}</g:link></td>

    <td>${list.crossref_url}</td>

    </tr>
      </g:each>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Anyone has an idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `<td>${list.id}</td>` wont work, `${list._id}` will do

Comment: thats it that was just a typo, thanks for the reply  injecteer!

Comment: how is the generated html looks like?